# How do I kill background tasks in Oreo programmatically?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I'm building a mobile app, and I'd like to implement a functionality where I can clean ram memory by killing background tasks in Android Oreo (something similar like CCleaner would do).

I've tried an algorithm I found on a GitHub. But it seemed to only work with Android 5.0

```
 protected void populateTextViewWithRunningProcesses() {
        // Empty the TextView
        mTextView.setText("");

        // Initialize a new instance of ActivityManager
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        // Get a list of RunningAppProcessInfo
        List<AndroidAppProcess> processes = AndroidProcesses.getRunningAppProcesses();

        // Display the number of running processes
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Running processes : " +
                runningProcesses.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Loop through the running processes
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
            // Get the process name
            mTextView.setText(mTextView.getText() + processInfo.processName + "\n");
        }
    }
```

It only shows my app's own tasks but not other running tasks

Comment: Yes! I mean, I want to get all other tasks like other app's task, so I can kill them an free up ram memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android 5.0+ killed getRunningTasks(int) and getRunningAppProcesses(). Both of those methods are now deprecated and only return your application process. You can get a list of running apps using UsageStatsManager. Check this example: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AppUsageStatistics